# How to hide action bar when scrolling down in RecycleView and make it appear when scrolling back up

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-recyclerview

I can't find anything on it, any help would be appreciated

Because I'm guessing this only applies for ListViews; https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView ?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a CoordinatorLayout and CollapsibleAppBar from the support libraries.